# Thymeleaf inserts a text in the HTML code

Tags: html, css, thymeleaf

I want to insert an attribute into the HTML Code.
I tried this, but it's not working:

```html
<div id="${var}"> ... </div>
```

I think you know what I mean. The attribute `var` should be the `ID`. I didn't find a solution...

Comment: did you try if work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to use the `th:attr` attribute. It is explained in the reference documentation 5.1:

- [5.1 Setting the value of any attribute](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#setting-attribute-values)

> Enter then the **th:attr attribute, and its ability to change the value
>   of attributes of the tags it is set in**:
>
> ```
> <form action="subscribe.html" th:attr="action=@{/subscribe}">  
>    <fieldset>
>     <input type="text" name="email" />
>     <input type="submit" value="Subscribe!" th:attr="value=#{subscribe.submit}"/>   
>     </fieldset> 
> </form>
> ```
>
> The
>   concept is quite straightforward: th:attr simply takes an expression
>   that assigns a value to an attribute. Having created the corresponding
>   controller and messages files, the result of processing this file will
>   be:
>
> ```
> <form action="/gtvg/subscribe">   
>    <fieldset>
>     <input type="text" name="email" />
>     <input type="submit" value="¡Suscríbe!"/>   
>   </fieldset> 
>  </form>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
<div th:attr="id=${var}"> ... </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thymeleaf only evaluates attributes that are prefixed with `th:`.  Here is a list of the attributes that are evaluated:

http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#setting-value-to-specific-attributes

In your case, `th:id` is already built in so you can simply do `<div th:id="${var}"> ... </div>` and it will work.  `th:attr`, is used to define attributes that thymeleaf doesn't normally support.